# Wicket AjaxCallListener getPrecondition method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I'm using AjaxLink and I want to stop it's "onClick" method execution on some circumstances. A solution for this is class called "AjaxCallListener", which has method "getPrecondition()", in which you can call any yours javascript function and wether the result is "false", then AjaxLink's "onClick" does not execute. This "AjaxCallListener" is added to attributes of ajaxRequest.

```
@Override protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
    attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new AjaxCallListener() {
        @Override public CharSequence getPrecondition(Component component) {
            return "isPropagationAllowed();";
        }
    });
}
```

then somewhere in our js file:

`function isPropagationAllowed() {
    alert('function called')
    return false;
}`

Alert is invoked, but the further execution on server still works.

Comment: What if youremove alert('')? Still don't work?

Comment: It didn't work because the result of that function did not return, so it's required to be done in Java explictly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write "return ${functionName}()" as a result of "getPrecondition" method:

```
@Override protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new AjaxCallListener() {
        @Override public CharSequence getPrecondition(Component component) {
            return "return isPropagationAllowed()";
        }
    });
}
```